# Question on the provability of the physics laws of the Newtonian Mechanic

Tags: laws-of-physics

Why the physical laws like Newton's law of motion can't be proved? Or more specifically: why our Universe follows laws?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA

No one can answer this question more beautifully than our very own Richard Feynman .

Comment: See [Why does the universe obey scientific laws?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/14352)

Answer (score 3):

Your first question makes a false assumption.

You have tacitly and wrongly accepted justificationism: the idea that it is possible or desirable to show that your ideas are true or probably true. If you assess ideas using argument then the arguments have premises and rules of inference and the result of the argument may not be true (or probably true) if the premises and rules of inference are false. You might try to solve this by coming up with a new argument that proves the premises and rules of inference but then you have the same problem with those premises and rules of inference. You might say that some stuff is indubitably true (or probably true), and you can use that as a foundation. But that just means you have cut off a possible avenue of intellectual progress since the foundation can't be explained in terms of anything deeper. And in any case there is nothing that can fill that role. Sense experience won't work since you can misinterpret information from your sense organs, e.g. - optical illusions. Sense organs also fail to record lots of stuff that does exist, e.g. - neutrinos. Scientific instruments aren't infallible either since you can make mistakes in setting them up, in interpreting information from them and so on.

We don't create knowledge (useful or explanatory information) by showing stuff is true or probably true for reasons so how do we create knowledge? We can only create knowledge by finding mistakes in our current ideas and correcting them piecemeal. You notice a problem with your current ideas, propose solutions, criticise the solutions until only one is left and then find a new problem. Experiments are useful only as criticism. Ideas can't be derived from experiment any more than from any other set of premises. Rather, the idea is that you work out how the consequences of one theory differ from those of another. Then you conjecture ideas about experimental setups that would enable you to see the relevant consequences and criticise them. Once you have a setup that works about as well as you can make it work you use it to do the test. If the results are compatible with one theory and not the others then you may have successfully refuted some false ideas. Sometimes a purported successful experimental test will be successfully criticised because a test is a conjecture about something that happened and that conjecture may be wrong, so experiments don't prove anything, nor do they support ideas.

Your second question is very vague so I don't think it has an answer as stated. It would be good if you could clarify what problem you are trying to address.

Answer (score 1):

1) Newtons laws CAN be proved, it just makes little sense to do so mathematically. Today we use them as a basis or a set of fundamental principles we know to be true so they are used to derive other mathematical truths. You could just as easily start with Lagranges equations and derive Newton's laws, but these proofs become circular.

The real way to prove Newtonian mechanics is to do so experimentally. Accelerate a mass and measure the force on it. Apply a force to a mass and measure the acceleration. Etc.

2) Why the Universe has a set of ordered laws that it follows is an unanswerable question. You might not like this, but neither has any philosopher ever. It is the reason some people are religious and it drives others to say that it is because it is (just a fundamental truth of our universe). There is no way to prove why it exists an theories as to why our universe follows the laws of physics are really just someones guess.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you said the proof becomes circular?

Comment: If you try to prove Newton's laws starting from Lagrange's formulations you end up needing a proof for Lagrange's formulations which needs Newton's laws which needs Lagrange. Basically you have to assume some starting point or a base to build from - most physicists today consider Newton's laws that base.

Answer (score 0):

Not true. They can be proved, based on a much deeper "layer" of the rules controlling the Universe. And these are the symmetries. For example, the time dilatation invariance, or the differente spacelike rotation/translation symmetries.

Using the list of these, there is a relative new mathematical proof, that practically only the rules of the Newtonian and the Special Relativistic mechanics have all of the symmetries. More about this question can you read [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114043/possible-mechanics-based-on-the-known-symmetries-in-the-nature-investigating-ru).